# I have 3 routers connected in one network, how can I change all three passwords?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have three routers connected to one network (1 cisco and 2 dlink). When I connect to each of the different routers with the ip address to change the wifi password I am connected to only one of the routers. How can I access the other two to change the wifi passwords for them?

Comment: Connect to the other two by using *their* IP addresses.

Comment: Set up each with a static address ie, 10.0.10.1 then .2 and .3. making it so that you can access all three without problems

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to connect to them individually. Because they each have the configuration stored locally, I don't think you can do this without logging into each one. You could always write a shell script and do it if ssh configuration is enabled on the routers. 
Use their individual IP addresses for the connection - if one router is at 192.168.1.2, then access 192.168.1.2. If you don't know their IPs, you could run an nmap scan to determine every device on your network and locate the routers, or access the device that assigns the routers their IPs.